# Unexpected floating-point representations in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, hashtable

Hello I am using a dictionary in Python storing some cities and their population like that:

```
population = { 'Shanghai' : 17.8, 'Istanbul' : 13.3, 'Karachi' : 13.0, 'mumbai' : 12.5 }
```

Now if I use the command `print population`, I get the result:

```
{'Karachi': 13.0, 'Shanghai': 17.800000000000001, 'Istanbul': 13.300000000000001, 'mumbai': 12.5}
```

whereas if I use the command `print population['Shanghai']` I get the initial input of `17.8`.

My question to you is how does the `17.8` and the `13.3` turned into `17.800000000000001` and `13.300000000000001` respectively? How was all that information produced? And why is it stored there, since my initial input denotes that I do not need that extra information, at least as far as I know.

Comment: The dictionary isn't what's behaving unexpectedly for you. You've just run into [Floating Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been changed in Python 3.1. From the [what's new](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.1.html#other-language-changes) page:

> Python now uses David Gay’s algorithm for finding the shortest
>   floating point representation that doesn’t change its value. This
>   should help mitigate some of the confusion surrounding binary floating
>   point numbers.
>
> The significance is easily seen with a number like `1.1` which does
>   not have an exact equivalent in binary floating point. Since there is
>   no exact equivalent, an expression like `float('1.1')` evaluates to
>   the nearest representable value which is `0x1.199999999999ap+0` in hex
>   or `1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625` in decimal.
>   That nearest value was and still is used in subsequent floating point
>   calculations.
>
> What is new is how the number gets displayed. Formerly, Python used a
>   simple approach. The value of `repr(1.1)` was computed as `format(1.1,
>   '.17g')` which evaluated to `'1.1000000000000001'`. The advantage of
>   using 17 digits was that it relied on IEEE-754 guarantees to assure
>   that `eval(repr(1.1))` would round-trip exactly to its original value.
>   The disadvantage is that many people found the output to be confusing
>   (mistaking intrinsic limitations of binary floating point
>   representation as being a problem with Python itself).
>
> The new algorithm for `repr(1.1)` is smarter and returns `'1.1'`.
>   Effectively, it searches all equivalent string representations (ones
>   that get stored with the same underlying float value) and returns the
>   shortest representation.
>
> The new algorithm tends to emit cleaner representations when possible,
>   but it does not change the underlying values. So, it is still the case
>   that `1.1 + 2.2 != 3.3` even though the representations may suggest
>   otherwise.
>
> The new algorithm depends on certain features in the underlying
>   floating point implementation. If the required features are not found,
>   the old algorithm will continue to be used. Also, the text pickle
>   protocols assure cross-platform portability by using the old
>   algorithm.
>
> (Contributed by Eric Smith and Mark Dickinson; [issue 1580](http://bugs.python.org/issue1580))

Answer (score 2):

You need to read up on how floating-point numbers work in computers.

Basically, not all decimal numbers are possible to store exactly, and in those cases you will get the closest possible number. Sometimes this abstraction leaks, and you get to see the error.

This is probably due to differences in the printing logic used for the two use-cases you describe. I couldn't re-produce the behavior (using Python 2.7.2 in Win64).

If you use a number that *is* exactly representable, such as `1.5`, I would guess the effect to go away.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I guess floating point numbers must be the case. I will leave this answer open to see if anyone else is gonna add something, for a while, and if not, I am gonna close it. Thanks again.

Comment: Nothing to add, unwind is correct on both points. When you "print" the dict, you get the internal representation of the float values, while when you print the float value you get the "stringyfied" (rounded) version. Try "print repr(population["shangai"])" and "print str(population["shangai"])"...

Answer (score 1):

You have to use decimal.Decimal if you want to have the decimal represented exactly as you specified it on any machine in the world.

See the Python manual for information: http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> print Decimal('3.14')
3.14
```

Comment: except take care -- `Decimal`s are still floating-point numbers, just with base 10 instead of base 2.